# Check if a variable is one of a set of valid strings

Tags: javascript, strings, comparative-review, validation, ecmascript-6

We need to check if a given variable is either `"get"` or `"post"`. If it's neither then I should throw an error.

My teammate and I disagree on the better solution.

One approach:

```
if (!['get', 'post'].includes(x)) {
  throw new Error('OhGodWhy')
}
```

A second approach:

```
if (x !== 'get' && x !== 'post') {
  throw new Error('OhGodWhy')
}
```

Which one would you choose and **why**?

Relevant note: Other values are likely to be added in the future (`'delete'`, `'update'` etc).

Comment: this sounds to me like you're looking for an "i told you so" as the obvious answer is the first one. you could also consider `toLowerCase()`ing it as well if it might ever be case ambiguous. edit: assuming you're running in a controlled environment as [`includes` is still very poorly supported.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) if not use `[].indexOf() > -1`

Comment: Not a case of "I told tou so", I am genuinely looking for your opinions. The environment is correctly set up to use es6.

Comment: Please show the code in context: what happens after the validation succeeds or fails? Are you writing a webserver or what? Are these HTTP methods?

Comment: @200_success what is the purpose of your edit?

Comment: To present the two versions neutrally, so that we don't immediately see which you prefer.

Comment: I'm not going to start an edit war so I'm leaving.

Answer (score 3):

> Which one would you choose and why?

The first example creates an array. Not a problem in single-use cases, but can become really expensive when you put it inside code that runs a lot (i.e. a render function, an observable subscription, socket handlers, etc.). As an effect, you'll also cause slight hitching in the UI because the GC kicks in more often.

Another issue is how `array.includes` work. If I remember correctly, `array.includes`, and it's polyfill implementation that uses `array.indexOf`, is `O(n)` - the more the items, the slower it gets. Not in this case, but it's a habit that is easily overlooked.

But this is a case of micro-optimization. I wouldn't worry about it unless you determine that it *is* really that slow (via profiling the code). However, for good practice, I would choose the second one (the direct check).

Alternatively, you can just have an object of methods that's outside hot code which you check against. You only have to create the object once, the lookup is `O(1)`, and adding more methods is as flexible as the array, where you don't have to meddle with the `if`.

```
const methods = { get: true, post: true }

if(!methods[x]) throw new Error('OhGodWhy')
```

Comment: I am aware of the better performance of the raw check. The code won't run inside any loop so the performance hit is negligible here (I agree the raw check is the winner in performance-critical situations). Using an object as a set is interesting, but it can be somewhat obscure as it's not a common technique, don't you agree? Maybe using the [actual set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is even better than all other current options.

Comment: @Gabriel If you're not constrained by legacy browsers, you can use `Set`. I just use objects out of habit. Objects and arrays are also easily serializable to JSON. Simplest solution is always better I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing something right after, which is based on x being `get` or `post`? Then I  would use a switch

```
switch(x) {
  case 'get':
    //Do something with get
    break;
  case 'post':
    //Do something with post
    break;
  default:
    throw new Error('OhGodWhy');
}
```

It's also easy to add more later.